# I want to show results based on the user's input without reloading the page! (For Wordpress webdesign in html?)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, input

please understand that I'm a total noob in coding.
I'm working on a page of my local Scouting community that allows the visitor to type a number (which represents the age of their child. Ages from 0 to 18), which has to put something in motion so that the troop their child belongs to, instantly shows up on the page (without refreshing the page).
This is my idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzAM6.jpg
(Text from the image:)
On the left side from top to bottom:
- Visitor can click on boy/girl
- Results shows directly after input. No Refreshing
- Content loads after an upwards motion
On the right side from top to bottom:
- Result remains on page until reload/backspace

About the website: https://www.eos-sthubertus.nl (Now under maintenance, so temporarily this website replaces the website stated above: http://eos.zellez.net)
We are a local Scouting community that had a really old UI (a 2005 look). Together with a few other people, we are modernising the website and complying our website to the GDPR.

Comment: Well, I tried numerous things, but everything didn't work out. Since I'm unexperienced, I mainly tried basic html stuff / somewhat dificult wordpress plugins (and editing a few code lines of plugins to realise what I would like).

Comment: 1) in the browser (javascript) catch an event to initiate data refresh. can be button click or input field change or key-up. use jquery.
2) send the request to the server via ajax https://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/
3) collect the data and create html output on the server (PHP)
4) receive the data in browser, in above example success:function(data) {), and display it accordingly using jquery.
you got a nice collection of techniques you got to learn for this 'little' task ;-)

Comment: @Beatroot thanks for answering. Learning something new can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to give you any specific code examples as you havn't added any code yourself to the question. This is a generic jQuery AJAX tutorial for WordPress that should get you up on your feet:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

You will be able to hook a javascript event to the boy/girl button to trigger the event:

https://api.jquery.com/click/